# Shall we have a community blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

[Trilogy](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) [sites](http://blog.serverfault.com/) do have it, [gaming](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/) has one... shall we too?

Downsides are that few people must volunteer to provide some content on regular basis -- anyone?

EDIT: As this topic seems to have some support, I think we should move forward and organize the details... maybe a chat meeting, say, [10 VI 2011, 16:00UTC](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/18/ten-fold?tab=schedule)? (Please either register or protest in comment.)

EDIT: Topic continues [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/we-are-making-the-community-blog).

Comment: I find the idea interesting, though I will not have time to contribute much... But I wonder what we {c|w}ould put on it: general comments on the site, reviews, ads, upcoming stats conference?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs/91509#91509

Comment: sorry will not be able to make it. Too late for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've come across a host of blogs via individuals profiles on this site. Perhaps to get the ball rolling individuals who participate in the community would be willing to "re-publish" old blog posts to stimulate discussion on particular topics. If people are interested in disseminating their work I would think it would be a good venue to get more exposure.

Here are a list of a few blogs I've started to follow since participating on this site (note this is not exhaustive, simply what I've found through randomly looking at peoples profiles, and blogs that are not too mathematically challenging for me to follow):

- [Rob Hyndman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman)
- [Cyrus Samii](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/96/cyrus-s)
- [Rick Wicklin](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2773/rick-wicklin)
- [Galit Shmueli](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1945/galit-shmueli)
- [Roland Stark](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2669/rolando2)
- [Neil McGuigan](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/74/neil-mcguigan)
- [Colin Gillespie](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/8/csgillespie)
- [Shane](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/5/shane)
- [Jeromy Anglim](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/183/jeromy-anglim)
- [Tal Galili](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/253/tal-galili)
- [John Myles White](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/303/john-myles-white)

Looking over the list I see many of the blogs have a large focus on various programming topics (which is of obvious interest to the community). But many have blogs posts relating to strictly statistical questions as well, and I think either would be perfectly reasonable within the scope of the site's blog. If people want more exposure re-hashing old posts for people who contribute to the site seems fair to me. Of course this is dependent on people volunteering their work for the community, but I'm just listing this as a potential option for generating content.

Also as a suggestion I think we could identify some particularly good questions and answers on the site, and then have the individuals expand those into full blog posts. Maybe not so much to add content to already excellent answers, but to simply garner more exposure for those particularly enlightening exchanges. Here are a few of my favorites;

- [In linear regression, when is it appropriate to use the log of an independent variable instead of the actual values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298/in-linear-regression-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-log-of-an-independent-var)
- [Logistic Regression: Which pseudo R-squared measure is the one to report (Cox & Snell or Nagelkerke)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3559/1036)
- [Is adjusting p-values in a multiple regression for multiple comparisons a good idea?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3200/1036)

If we identify recurring questions we could perhaps make a blog post to attempt to expand and identify key features of those recurring questions as well.

Comment: +1 Good job listing; in deed I was hoping for such a vision of this blog to arise.

Answer (score 7):

Good idea. Would help greatly in promoting the site. I could volunteer to write one blog post a month :) But the main question is the one pointed out by @chl what would blog be about? I have few ideas for blog post, which I never found the time to post, but they are more R related. One is about my experience translating Eviews code to R, another about simple Rcpp example, another about how using R classes might help in writing simulation code. I feel though such blog posts would be  more about me showing off than anything else, which would not be helpful for community.

Comment: Considering the amount of programming questions related to R on the site those sound like reasonable and helpful topics to blog about. Don't sell yourself so short!