# We are making the community blog

Tags: discussion, blog

Following [this question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862/shall-we-have-a-community-blog) and [this chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/conversation/community-blog-discussion), community blog begins to emerge.

We already have three committed contributors: [Andy W](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1036/andy-w), [JMS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/26/jms) and [mpiktas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2116/mpiktas); kudos! (Of course anyone can join this group, even temporarily)

There will be a weekly survey for choosing a *Question of the Week* which will be later discussed on the blog ([similar idea on SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week)). The first survey is [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/871/the-question-of-the-week-1).

All the details, questions, ideas, stuff have their place on the newly created chat room devoted exclusively to the CV blog: **[Skewed distribution](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/549/skewed-distribution)**

Comment: Shall we put ideas for "general" posts here, in the chat, or someplace else? It might be good to have a "stack" of topics we can pull from & vote on.

Comment: @JMS This is rather something between an ad and FAQ; I think the chat room is a proper place for that.

Comment: @JMS, I think talking about what the community wants to see on the blog, topics, etc are fine on meta.  The community very much should have / has a voice in this.

Comment: @Rebecca I was worried that this post could get cluttered with such discussions; of course I have nothing against new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And so [the blog](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/) is up and running.