# The Question of the Week #1

Tags: discussion, blog, question-of-the-week

We are [making a community blog](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/we-are-making-the-community-blog), and we want to use community-selected intriguing questions as one of the topic sources, [as it is done on SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=15). The idea is to make it on a weekly basis so the whole would stay reasonably fresh.

Thus, please propose and vote for questions from the last week you think deserve blogging about as answers to this question.

Comment: Why do we have to limit it to the previous week?  This seems like an artificial distinction.

Comment: @whuber I think the motivation was to call attention to "timely" questions with a question of the week (and to help ensure weekly posts). Older questions could (and should) form the basis for other posts, of course.

Comment: @JMS Unlike some other forums, timeliness is rarely an issue here: questions and answers from many years ago can be (or should be) fresh.  I'm suggesting that we not hobble ourselves with unconsidered emulation of what other communities might be doing.

Comment: @whuber you make a good point. Wish we had you in the chat the other day :P

Comment: @JMS We can't accommodate everybody's schedules around the world.  The time of that chat happened to coincide with a previously committed part of my day.  I did have a nice conversation with Rebecca Chernoff the previous evening about blogging on SE (and I believe that's one reason why she participated in yesterday's chat).

Comment: @whuber Sorry if that sounded snarky; not intended at all! I do recognize that even if we were all in the same timezone coordinating would be difficult, and given the reality it's impossible. All I meant was that your consistently thoughtful and valuable input was missed.

Comment: @JMS @whuber You are at least at the same continent! (-;

Comment: another advantage of this question is (if asked regularly) that it serves as a newsletter for casual site visitors.

Comment: There was an eye, so I used R to select the winner randomly. Details are on chat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one is kind of an oldie, but got a bump recently:

[Good GUI for R suitable for a beginner wanting to learn  programming in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/good-gui-for-r-suitable-for-a-beginner-wanting-to-learn-programming-in-r)

A post comparing some of the options might be nice. It may take more than one of us, given platform differences, etc.

Answer (score 9):

My vote would be for [Essential data checking tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11659/1036).

The pertinence of the topic to this community I think would be obvious. So for a few other reasons why I think this would be a good blog post:

1. Its non-technical nature makes it accessible to a wide audience.
2. I think it would be of interest to a wider audience across the stack.exchange sites, and so would be a good platform to gain stats.se some exposure to members of other sites.

Comment: There's an interesting twist on this topic that makes it very timely: the new challenge to [Efficiently Recognize Anomalous Data in a Database Regardless of Context](https://www.innocentive.com/ar/challenge/9932624) offers a prize ($30K US) for an automated solution to the original question.

Answer (score 5):

I think this one is an interesting question with an excellent answer:

[How to tell if data is “clustered” enough for clustering algorithms to produce meaningful results?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11691/how-to-tell-if-data-is-clustered-enough-for-clustering-algorithms-to-produce-me)

I vote for this question because clustering is a very recurring topic, the idea behind clustering is simple but usually it is quite hard to get results in practice.

The question I proposed already has an accepted answer, and it deals with the gap statistic. The quality of the answer is outstanding.

Comment: Thank you.