# The Question of the Week #2

Tags: discussion, blog, question-of-the-week

We had selected our [first Question of the Week](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/871/the-question-of-the-week-1), now, when the blog has finally started, is time to continue the series.

Thus, please propose and vote for recent questions you think deserve blogging about as answers to this question. The winning question will be selected next Monday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have been several questions on the site that more or less ask about clustering longitudinal data.

- [Is it possible to do time-series clustering based on curve shape?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/is-it-possible-to-do-time-series-clustering-based-on-curve-shape)
- [Time series 'clustering' in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/time-series-clustering-in-r)
- [Modelling longitudinal data where the effect of time varies in functional form between individuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/modelling-longitudinal-data-where-the-effect-of-time-varies-in-functional-form-be)
- [How to find groupings (trajectories) among longitudinal data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13442/how-to-find-groupings-trajectories-among-longitudinal-data) (This is the most recent question)

This one may be another that could be quite large in scope (similar to the now series on R GUI's). Perhaps to reduce the workload we could get volunteers to write a brief abstract about different routines people have developed and applied examples.

Panel data that these techniques are applied to tend to be really complicated, and so it seems to me these clustering techniques can be really helpful for exploratory data analysis. The techniques being more complicated make it more difficult to make a blog post accessible to a wide audience, but I suspect the number of people working with similar panel data would make the post of interest to a large number of the members of this site.

Comment: (+1) neither complexity nor coverage of a subarea should one prevent from blogging about it. The internet is already full of basic articles about basic topics (although some fail to explain the topic they are about). Maybe writing a short intro article to this whole area beforehand might help ?

Answer (score 3):

*I am going to interpret "recent" liberally, in part because many of our questions and their answers will remain timely for years.  Why limit ourselves, then, to material posted only in the last few weeks?*

A wonderful foil for an ongoing blog, in fact, would be a series of exegeses on the replies to [Famous statistical quotations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/726/famous-statistician-quotes) .  Read through them, pick a quotation that resonates with you (or with which you disagree sharply!), and share with the world the context in which it arose, what controversy it might have been involved in, what it means, how it connects with your statistical experience, and anything else you can offer to bring it to life and help us appreciate its interest and importance.

Comment: That's why the reformulation from "last week" to "recent" (=

Comment: @mbq I appreciate the flexibility that offers: thanks!