# The Question of the Week #3

Tags: discussion, blog, question-of-the-week

We had selected our [first](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/871/the-question-of-the-week-1) and [second Question of the Week](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/904/the-question-of-the-week-2), so is time to continue the series.

Thus, please propose and vote for recent questions you think deserve blogging about as answers to this question. The winning question will be selected next Monday.

Answer (score 1):

The [network of cross-referenced posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/how-to-compute-the-probability-associated-with-absurdly-large-z-scores/13809#13809) by @Cardinal on **estimating tail probabilities of the Normal distribution** is worth highlighting and memorializing: it's a clearly described, useful body of work.  To help us appreciate this better, a blog post could provide some background: why do we care about such tail probabilities, what are the applications, and what are the basic problems with computing them.